# Google App Engine: Get source link to entity property

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine

I'm new to Google App Engine so I was hoping that you could help me here.

I'm trying to get the source link to a property of an entity (want to download a json), but can't figure out how.

This is the code:

```
<%-- //[START all]--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.User" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory" %>
<%-- //[START imports]--%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FetchOptions" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query" %>
<%-- //[END imports]--%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Mandatory Assigment 2</title>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Mandatory Assignment 2</h1>

    <p>This page shows the CSV files uploaded</p>

    <h2>Uploaded CSV files</h2>
    <%-- //[START datastore]--%>
    <%
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Key guestbookKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Guestbook", "guestbookName");
    // Run an ancestor query to ensure we see the most up-to-date
    // view of the Greetings belonging to the selected Guestbook.
    Query query = new Query("Greeting", guestbookKey).addSort("date", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);
    List<Entity> greetings = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(5));
    if (greetings.isEmpty()) {

    %>
    <p>There are no CSV files. Please refresh to reload</p>
    <%

    } else {
    %>
    <p>CSV files: </p>
    <%
    for (Entity greeting : greetings) {
        pageContext.setAttribute("greeting_content",
                greeting.getProperty("content"));
        if (greeting.getProperty("user") == null) {
    %>
    <p>An anonymous person wrote:</p>
    <%
    } else {
    pageContext.setAttribute("greeting_user",
            greeting.getProperty("user")); 
%>
    <p>json string: ${fn:escapeXml(greeting_content)}</a></a></p>
<%
    }
%>
<blockquote></blockquote>
<%
        }
    }
%>  

</body>
</html>
<%-- //[END all]--%>
```

The "${fn:escapeXml(greeting_content)}" code outputs the json as a String, but I would like to be able to download the json instead like this:

```
<p><a href="${fn:escapeXml(greeting_content)}">download JSON</a></a></p>
```

Can someone help me? I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<p><a href="${fn:escapeXml(greeting_content)}" download="name.json">download JSON</a></a></p>
```

Adding download attribute you can make content downloadable in the format you specified

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to improve your answer quality.

Comment: Sorry, adding download attribute you can make content downloadable in the format you specified.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But here comes the naive question: how can the download="name.json" know where to find the correct json?

Comment: @PæturMagnussen In href you pass the data, and download take this data and make this downloadable with the name you specified, and in this name you specify the format of file too.

Comment: @PæturMagnussen ex: if you put download="name.txt" the content of the file you download is the same but in diferent format.